# connection.getMetaData() getting called for every select query in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

I am executing select queries in my java app using org.hibernate.SQLQuery. The code is as below.

```
Query query=session.createSQLQuery("query");
query.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
List<Map<String,Object>> aliasToValueMapList=query.list();
```

The problem is, the oracle AWR report shows that there is another query that fires up with every select query I execute.

```
SELECT NULL AS table_cat, o.owner AS table_schem, o.object_name AS table_name, o.object_type AS 
table_type, NULL AS remarks FROM all_objects o WHERE o.owner LIKE :1 ESCAPE '/' AND o.object_name 
LIKE :2 ESCAPE '/' AND o.object_type IN ('xxx', 'TABLE') ORDER BY table_type, table_schem, table_name
```

Can anyone explain why this happens and how can I avoid this(I want to avoid this as this is the most CPU consuming query listed in the report)?

Answer (score 0):

I could find this which exactly deals with my problem. I am going test the suggestions given in the link. I will update the result here once I figure out the right solution.

[How to avoid this very heavy query that slows down the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630613/how-to-avoid-this-very-heavy-query-that-slows-down-the-application)